# Dativ plural: den or denen

Tags: grammatical-number, dative, relative-clause

I’ve always learned that the article for Dativ Plural is *den*, for example

> Ich kenne die Frauen, **den** man Bücher schenkt.

My Duden grammar agrees with me, but it is more common to see forms such as this:

> Ich kenne die Frauen, **mit denen** er spricht.

My understanding is then that *denen* is the relative pronoun, and *den* is the article. Is this correct? *Denen* is new to me.

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct/incomplete and thus a bit ambiguous... both "den" and "denen" can be Dativ plural.

Comment: Yes, *denen* is a [relative pronoun](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen), and you must have misread the Duden, because your first sentence is certainly wrong.

Comment: Is it 'man' or 'mann' ?? Sorry, I'm a bit confused aha.

Comment: "man" = "one/you". "der Mann" = "the man".

Answer (score 18):

You’re right with your statement that *[den](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Artikel)* is the article and *[denen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/der#Relativpronomen.2C_m.2C_f)* is the relative pronoun.

That said, in your first example you need the relative pronoun, not an article. Note that an article always precedes the noun. In the following examples I marked the articles and pronouns.

> Ich kenne **die**[article] Frauen, **denen**[relative pronoun] man Bücher schenkt.
>   **Den**[article] Frauen, mit **denen**[relative pronoun] er spricht, schenkt man Bücher.